# Entity Framework 6.2 not respecting TableAttribute on some computers

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have a .NET 4.5 WPF application that directly accesses a MS SQL database via Entity Framework 6.2. The app runs perfectly fine on most computers of our customer, however there is one system where our app cannot access the database because EF creates SQL statements internally that reference a table that does not exist:

> System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException: An error occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner exception for details. --->
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: **Invalid object name 'dbo.Configurations'.**

Our configuration entity looks like this:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace SomeNamespace
{
    [Table("Configuration")]
    public class Configuration : EntityBase
    {
        [Required]
        [MaxLength(50)]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string Value { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Username { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Our DbContext class looks like this (excerpt):

```
public class SomeContext : DbContext
{
    public virtual DbSet<Configuration> Configurations { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<SomeContext>(null);
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

**Why is the `TableAttribute` ignored by EF on some systems?** To me, it's obvious that EF does not respect the `TableAttribute` in this case because it wants to access the `dbo.Configurations` table (derived from the Configurations property of the DbContext) instead of `dbo.Configuration` using the name from the attribute. **The funny thing is that this only happens on one computer** - on all other ones, the app just runs fine.

I suspected that an older version of EF is installed in the GAC which is loaded instead of the EF DLL that I deploy with our app - thus I set **Specific Version** to true in the project references (Entity Framework was not added to the project via NuGet). This did not solve the problem.

I think that a quick solution would be to not use attributes but the fluent API instead. However, does anybody know why this problem occurs in the first place?

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: This is almost certainly nothing to do with EF and likely your code too. Are you sure you have the right code deployed on that machine? Are you launching the correct executable?

Comment: @DavidG Unfortunately, we have no direct access (yet) to the customer's system where the app is not working. We provided an installer that we assume was executed correctly on the target system by the customer's admins. I also think that it probably is a .NET configuration problem instead of a EF internal issue - but I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: If you don't even know what is going on with the remote computer, I suggest you figure that out first. There's no point asking us to help diagnose the issue without that knowledge.

Comment: my guess is that `[Table("Configuration")]` should be `[Table("Configurations")]`  or ensure  `modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();` is set so that when querys are built it knows not to plural the table name.

Comment: I would move your `Database.SetInitializer<SomeContext>(null);` out of the overload and put it on the contractor off SomeContext rather, as its less likely to mess with the internals of ef

Comment: May be you should take a clooser look at the gac content of the computer failing to work correctly?

Comment: Yeah, Alexander, I will try to to attach WinDbg if I'm lucky to get a grip of that computer. Unfortunately, the corresponding person is pretty high up the ranks in our customer's company so I doubt that I can access it in the near future.

Comment: @Seabizkit The target table is actually called `dbo.Configuration` (without the s). So, the attribute `[Table("Configuration"]` is actually correct.